# Logging output in Cloudant

Tags: database, logging, nosql, couchdb, cloudant

Is it possible to use the `log` method in Cloudant to log output in javascript functions? I know it can be done in CouchDB. The problem is that I don't know whether the log file is provided or not in Cloudant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of the `log` function is not exposed to users in Cloudant at the moment so, although using it won't break you indexes, it's not very useful unfortunately.

Comment: Seems like an important feature to be missing. Any reason why this is still not available to users?

Comment: has this ever been added? need to debug a complex view

Comment: It has not been added, no.

Comment: So is there any way you can possibly debug Cloudant reduce functions?